# Mac to HIteker Tv through HDMI

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi

Recently we have moved my HDMI cable to use on a different TV and when I brought it back to my room and used it to connect my MacBook Pro to my Hiteker TV, my mac recognizes the TV but the Tv doesn't recognize the Mac, it says no signal. I've tried putting the cable in the other HDMI port and the same thing happened. I have also unplugged it while both are on. Please help.

Comment: That's just the brand. Yes there's a button that lets you switch sources from the remote

Comment: as your Mac does recognize it, as what ?

Comment: also assuming it is not the cable since you double checked that ?

Comment: Well my mac screen flashes as it usually does when I plug the cable in and the TV is turned on and in the top bar I get the little screen with the triangle in it allowing me to select the mirroring option ect. but the tv screen says no signal

Comment: Sorry, I mean does the Mac show the TV by name in the syst pref or in the about this mac ? You should also see it in the ColorSync Utility located in your utility folder. Recognizing is only the first step (like hand shake) the step following is they boot have to agree on how to talk. /what ICC profile to use, refresh rate and so on.

Comment: When I go to About this Mac and go to displays it shows the TV as MTC26T42 Display. It also shows it as an option under displays in the ColorSync Utility folder

Comment: ok is there a way I could check this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, we are beating around the bushes here, so to make progress this is for your Information and not a answer to your problem.

The MTC26T42 is a Nvidia HD Audio, not a display!

Here is what you should look for (example for my Samsung TV) connected via Thunderbolt to HDMI-HDMI.

This is from the About this Mac (notice it says Television: Yes.)

[image: about]

This one is from the system preference -Display

[image: display]

And this is information from the ColorSync Utility.

[image: colorsync]